# Spring Rest Template - why i get "whitelabel error"?

Tags: api, spring-mvc, resttemplate

Hi i want to make very simple application that print an  openweathermap.org API answer in console. I thought it should works, but when i'm going to an adress in my browser i've got Whitelabel Error Page and nothing in console. I've made two classes. Main:

```
package com.example.restTemplate;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestTemplateApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestTemplateApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

and controller:

```
package com.example.restTemplate.Controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;

@RestController
public class ConsumeWebService {
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "localhost:8080/weather")
    public void printWeather() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        System.out.println(restTemplate.exchange("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&myAPIKey", 
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody()); 
    }
}
```

Of course i didn't put here my real key to API and i should to declared city and key in params, but i will think about it in future. For now i just want to get a simple output in console and wll be appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you put `"localhost:8080/weather"` as value?

Change from

```
@RequestMapping(value ="localhost:8080/weather")
```

To

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/weather")
```

Comment: You're right. I don't know too. Thanks a lot. :)